# is it possible to make custom shaped buttons in iOS

Tags: ios

Or some kind of UI objects that can

1. interact with users
2. be drawn into any shape, for example, oval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do it in a variety of ways. Rydgaze gave you the option for using a UIImage as your custom button. If you are looking for a code only way then I would suggest UIBezierPath. UIBezierPath allow's you to draw any shape that you want as well as customize the look. With UIBezierPath I could draw a star and fill it with anything that I would like.

Here is the link to the Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html

The idea is that you create a view class. In that view's drawRect method you will design whatever shape you are looking to create and customize it to what you see fit. For you button you would set its self.view to be the view that of your custom UIBezierPath class. That will just draw your custom shape as the button.

The advantage's to writing your button's in code are that it will for one be faster. It also takes up significantly less size because it isn't storing an image file. Also you are able to continue the customization of your shape. That mean's you could change the color, dimensions, etc. very easily.

Answer (score 1):

yes. It is pretty simple.

```
  UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenButton.png"];
  UIImage *buttonImageHighlight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenButtonHighlight.png"];


 [myCustomButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [myCustomButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```